# I keep losing my wife in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married *Jenassa* and I keep losing her. I went back to our house to look for her & The Drunken Huntsman's place too but I can't find her anywhere.

Comment: Are you on PC or Xbox/PS4?

Comment: I am on an Xbox-360

Comment: Have you tried loading an earlier save? see if that helps maybe?

Comment: I went back to Solitude and I found her. Do you know where I can pick up some things for kids?

Comment: I believe in general stores you should be able to find some. Also you should put an answer in this question just for good measure. :P

Comment: You really shouldn't have put the "in Skyrim" part to your title it would have been much funnier.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't own a house spouses tend to have a location they fallback to so if you lose them (again) check their default hangouts and they are likely there.

List of spouse locations (and more) [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#NPCs_available_to_be_married)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your wife to stay put, you have to own a house and tell her to live there.

You can move your wife from house to house, but once you own property you'll have a dialogue option that will tell her where to go and where to stay.

Comment: I have had a house and two kids and she was there one minute gone the next and found her in solitude. Now she stands on Sofie's bed and never moves...

Comment: If that's the case, her character movement is caught. Basically each character in Skyrim follows a script on where to go and what to do. They basically get caught on items or whatever. What I do is run into them, FUS ROH DAH (make sure they don't try to kill you after) or maybe some other magic spell that makes them move.